# AtomicInteger vs synchronized getters/setters

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Is this class thread-safe?

Is it possible to see inconsistent values? Lets say initially a's value is 80. Thread 1 calls `setA(100)` and enters the function but did not yet call `a.set(100)` and Thread 2 concurrently calls `getA()`. Is it possible for Thread 2 to see 80?

```
public class A {
    private AtomicInteger a; 

    public int getA() {
        return a.get()
    }

    public void setA(int newVal){
        a.set(newVal);
    }   
}
```

I know that synchronizing it will guarantee thread 2 sees 100, but not sure with AtomicInteger.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is this class thread-safe?

Yes it is.

> Thread 1 calls setA(100) and enters the function but did not yet call a.set(100) and Thread 2 concurrently calls getA().   Is it possible for Thread 2 to see 80?

Yes.  Until the memory barrier code that synchronizes the volatile field inside of `AtomicInteger` completes, the race condition can show 80 or 100.

Thread 1 could even enter the `AtomicInteger.set` method and be before the inner field assignment and still the 80 may be returned by get `AtomicInteger.get` method.

There are no guarantees about *when* the values will be updated in other threads. What is guaranteed is when the `get()` completes, you get the most recent synchronized value and when the `set()` completes, all other threads will see the updates.

There is no guarantee as to the *timing* of getter and setter calls in different threads.

Answer (score 1):

As @Gray noted, there is a possibility for a race condition here.

Calling `get` and then `set` is not an atomic operation. [The `Atomic*` classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) offer a lock-free atomic conditional update operation, `compareAndSet` - you should use that one for thread safety.